# How to use terms facet for a string field in SOLR

Tags: solr

Consider the following 4 fields and their type definitions in a SOLR schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField >.....</fieldType>
<fieldType name="float" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" />
<fieldType name="bool" class="solr.BoolField" />  
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />

<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="inStock" type="bool" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<field name="category" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" />
```

Now, I am running these 4 queries:

```
{ "query" : "*:*", "facet": { "test" : { "type": "terms", "field": "title" }}}
{ "query" : "*:*", "facet": { "test" : { "type": "terms", "field": "price" }}}
{ "query" : "*:*", "facet": { "test" : { "type": "terms", "field": "inStock" }}}
{ "query" : "*:*", "facet": { "test" : { "type": "terms", "field": "category" }}}
```

The last one will give me:

```
"facets": {
    "count": 2354,
    "test": {
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
```

While all the other ones work, e.g for the price, I'll get:

```
"facets": {
    "count": 2354,
    "test": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "val": 5.4958,
          "count": 3
        },
        {
          "val": 1.6593,
          "count": 2
        },
        {
          "val": 2.5,
          "count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

It's not clear to me why I get facets for `FloatPointField`, `BoolField` and `TextField`, but not for `StrField`. Also when I use `multiValued="true"` for the `StrField`, it doesn't calculate any facets.

Comment: Are you sure that the field "category" is correctly populated with array data? The query you wrote should work as expected.